# Trying to turn Normal code into a method/ function

Tags: c#

```
 class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          int[] search = { 88, 62, 5, 18, 22, 78, 13, 8, 33, 7 };
          Console.WriteLine("Enter value to find");
          int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          int place = -1;
          for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
          {
              
              if (search[i]== val)
              {
                  place = i +1;
              }
             

          }
          if(place == -1)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("The Target Value was not found in the list");
              Console.ReadLine();
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("The Target Value was found at location: " + place);
              Console.ReadLine();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to search for an entered value in an array, and I got that working, now I want to make it a method/ function but I have no idea how.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2019

Comment: What part about it is confusing? Do you just not know how to create/call methods?

Comment: I do not know how to create methods

Comment: What research have you done? Using methods is a rather fundamental part of programming, so I would expect just about every c# introduction to have sufficient information to solve this this. Is there something about existing explanations you do not understand?

Comment: You already have a method called `Main` that contains your code. Not sure what the question is.

Comment: You might want to look into some basic C# tutorials.. Like a previous comment said, methods are a very basic/fundamental building block. Creating them is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's start *extracting methods*. We can begin with user input:

```
 private static int ReadInteger(string prompt) {
   while (true) {
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(prompt))
       Console.WriteLine(prompt);

     // What if user put "bla-bla-bla"? That's why we TryParse (not Parse)
     if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
       return result;

     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid integer value. Please, try again.");
   }
 }
```

Then continue with `FindIndex`

```
 // Let's put IEnumerable<int> which allows not only array, but list, hashset etc.
 private static int FindIndex(IEnumerable<int> values, int toFind) {
   if (values == null)
     return -1;

   int index = 0;

   foreach (int value in values) {
     index += 1;

     if (value == toFind)
       return index;    
   }
   
   return -1;    
 }
```

Finally, we call them from `Main`:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   int[] search = { 88, 62, 5, 18, 22, 78, 13, 8, 33, 7 };

   int place = FindIndex(search, ReadInteger("Enter value to find"));

   Console.WriteLine(place >= 0 
     ? $"The Target Value was found at location: {place}"
     : "The Target Value was not found in the list"
   );

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```